# Floating divs for responsive website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float divs for a responsive website and it's not working properly. I need them to be in the order below because when the screen gets smaller, they need to stack with 1 on top, then 2, the 3. The third div is not going nicely underneath the first div. Any help is appreciated!

```
<div class="1">info</div>
<div class="2">info</div>
<div class="3">info</div>

.1 {
width:23%;
float:right;
}
.2 {
width:76%;
float:left;
}
.3 {
float:right;
width:23%;
}
```

Again, just to be clear, I need "3" to be underneath "1" but it's going underneath "2". Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't help, it just pushes it further down below "2". This is on a dev site, access is restricted by IP.

Comment: Have you tried using a Media Query, and clearing the divs when viewed on a mobile? Give them all a 100% width, and clear:both. They should then stack ontop of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Css Class shouldn't begin with number.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skabwk5q/)

```
.one {
width:23%;
float:right;
}
.two {
width:76%;
float:left;
}
.three {
float:right;
width:23%;
}
```

Comment: It's just an example. The real class has a name.

Comment: when you change the right and left. i't will work. i had updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want [Demo](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/qEwqQE)

```
  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .one {
      width:23%;
      float:left;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  .two {
      width:76%;
      float:left;
      background-color: #666;
  }
  .three {
      float:left;
      width:23%;
      background-color: #ddd;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess using inline block will work. Even if you resize the window without the percentage width.

```
.one {
    width:23%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: yellow;

}
.two {
    width:76%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: orange;
}
.three {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    width:23%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skabwk5q/4/)

Answer (score 0):

your code was right, except that css-classes must not start or only contain a number. DIV.two does not nedd to float:

```
<div class="one">info 1</div>
<div class="two">info 2</div>
<div class="three">info 3</div>
```

And the css:

```
.one {
width:23%;
float:right;
background-color: yellow;
}
.two {
width:76%;
background-color: grey;
}
.three {
float:right;
width:23%;
background-color: red;
}
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skabwk5q/6/).